# Foreach parallelization process multiple errors

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I have to do statistics on a raster representing whole Scotland with a 25m resolution. To speed up the processes I want to parallelize them, by dividing the raster.

I firstly changed my code into a sequential foreach loop which is working. 
When I change my foreach loop into a parallel one I got multiple errors, changing at each Run. 
e.g :

> Error in { : task 3 failed - "length(values) is not equal to ncell(x), or to 1"

or

> Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'yn' not found"

or

> Error in { : task 2 failed - "'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'"

To check which core has ended its process, I save a dbf file with the data 
produced during the process at the end. But it isn't the same files that are saved at each run, e.g. sometimes the file number 1 and 3 are saved, at the next run the number 2 and 3 are the ones saved and at the next time only the number 4 is saved etc...

This is my parallelisation code :

```
  Mask_Shp  <- shapefile(B_2kmSquares)
  LCM       <- raster(BaselineLUmap)

  mask_crs  <- Mask_Shp@proj4string

  if (detectCores()>4) {
    cl <- makeCluster(detectCores()-4,type="FORK",outfile="")

    library(SpaDES)
    list_LCM <- splitRaster(LCM,2,length(cl)%/%2,0)


  } else cl <- NULL

  registerDoParallel(cl) # this is to detect and register the number of cores

  print("Start Parallelization")

  Output_DataFrame <- foreach(i=1:length(cl), .combine = rbind, 
                              .packages = c("raster","rgdal","rgeos","plyr","tictoc","foreign"
                                            ,"pscl","data.table")) %dopar% {***code***}
  stopCluster(cl)
```

I can't understand those errors and problems.

Does anyone have encountered similar issues ? 
Or does anyone have an idea of what could be the issue ?

Comment: Looks like some objects needed are not exported to the nodes. Tell `foreach` explicitly to export them (see the documentation).

Comment: Why some of my processes reach the end if some objects are missing ?

Comment: Dunno. You helpfully left out the relevant part of your code.

Comment: It did not seem relevent to me to put 400 lines of code there.

Comment: You are right. But you are supposed to provide a *minimal reproducible example*. Without any code, we can only guess, which I is what I have done.

Comment: I don't think I can make a reproducible example, there's too many input needed and too many processes in the foreach loop. Thank you for help tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached to get out of this by following Roland advices in the comments : 
 puting in the `.export` variable of the `foreach()` function the variables declared outside of the `foreach` loop.

**AND** by changing my combine mode from `.combine = rbind` to `.combine = rbind.data.frame` as each of my processes was returning a dataframe.